# Call static function only after onListen is triggered

Tags: java, android, flutter

I am integrating Serial Communication plugin from https://pub.dev/packages/serial_communication in my Flutter app. But the app keep crashing. I only know Flutter, so I need help in Java.

I printed all the log, and it seems like it will not be null only after onListen function is being triggered. But how to control and make sure my static function can only started after onListen is being called?

Here is the full code for the class.

```
class CustomEventHandler extends BroadcastReceiver implements EventChannel.StreamHandler {
    static EventChannel.EventSink events;
    static final Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void onListen(Object arguments, EventChannel.EventSink events) {
        System.out.println("onListen successful " + events);
        this.events = events;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(Object arguments) {
        events = null;
    }

    static void sendEvent(final Map<String,String> response) {
        if (response != null && events != null && mainHandler != null) {
            System.out.println("sendEvent successful " + events + response + mainHandler);
            Runnable runnable = () -> events.success(response);
            if(runnable != null) {
                mainHandler.post(runnable);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("sendEvent failed " + events + response + mainHandler);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (events != null) {
            events.success("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

The null value always come from variable EventChannel.EventSink "events". But the sendEvent function is being called in other class. Here is the code :

```
public void initData() {

    spManager = SerialApiManager.getInstances().setLogInterceptor(new LogInterceptorSerialPort() {
        @Override
        public void log(@SerialApiManager.Type final String type, final String port, final boolean isAscii, final String log) {
            if (log != null) {
                logChannel = (new StringBuffer()
                        .append(log).toString());

                CustomEventHandler.sendEvent(  Map.of("LogChannel", logChannel, "readChannel", readChannel));
            }
        }

    });
    baseReader = new BaseReader() {
        @Override
        protected void onParse(final String port, final boolean isAscii, final String read) {
            if (read != null) {
                readChannel = (new StringBuffer()
                        .append(read).toString());
                
                CustomEventHandler.sendEvent(  Map.of("LogChannel", logChannel, "readChannel", readChannel));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I don't have any idea how to solve this. Can you help me?